# docker-compose.yml volumes is not mounted to the target container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mounted-volumes, container-image

Ater too much googling I can't find a solution.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  system:
    build: .
    container_name: apo_api
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
    - '1122:80'
```

The container builds and runs successfully but the `/var/www/html` folder is empty when sshed into the container.
Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you very much

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04

**Docker version**: 19.03.13

Comment: Can you try replacing `./` with the absolute path under volumes?

Comment: @akazuko I tried this. But still not working

Comment: Did you try it with a different image (e.g. `image: alpine` instead of `build: .`) - to see if its an image issue or a system issue?